# constraint error on indexeddb database when updating version and nothing else

Tags: indexeddb

I'm having problems with this code when I upgrade the version without any other modification, and I can't understand the reason.

```
function create_registry() {
    var version = 1;
    var indexeddb_db = "examples"; // database
    var indexeddb_table = "examples_table"; // table

    // open the database
    var indexeddb_request = indexedDB.open( indexeddb_db, version ); // connect + open database
    var db = false;

    // if error
    indexeddb_request.onerror = function ( event ) {
        console.log( event.target );
        console.trace();
    }

    // if success
    indexeddb_request.onsuccess = function ( event ) {
        console.log( event.target );
        console.trace();
    }

    // if onupgradeneeded
    indexeddb_request.onupgradeneeded = function( event ) {
        console.log( event.target );
        console.trace();
        db = event.target.result;
        var objectStore = db.createObjectStore( indexeddb_table, { keyPath: 'url' } );
    }

}
```

The first time that the page is loaded, the indexedDB object (database) is created and the table inside is created. Everything works fine. First the onupgradeneeded is executed and then the onsuccess is launched.

If I reload the page without any changes, everything works fine, the onsuccess is launched.

But, if I change the version number, then I get the errors mentioned below. Those errors are described briefly in the [W3C spec of the Indexed Database API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-IndexedDB-20130704/#exceptions), but that doesn't help me much so far. After the onupgradeneeded is executed, the onerror is execute and there I have an AbortError, but that doesn't tell me much more either.

> Chrome 28
>   "Uncaught Error: ConstraintError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 0"
>
> Firefox 22
>   "A mutation operation in the transaction failed because a constraint was not satisfied. For example, an object such as an object store or index already exists and a request attempted to create a new one. "

As far as I can tell, the problem is that I'm trying to recreate the same object with the same keypath, but isn't the new version making the script recreate the whole object?

Why Am I getting the error?
Shouldn't the onupgradeneeded just update the version number and rewrite the object (database)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As far as I can tell, the problem is that I'm trying to recreate the same object with the same keypath

That is correct. Although the keypath has nothing to do with it, it's just that the object store has the same name as an existing object store.

> isn't the new version making the script recreate the whole object?

No. Object stores (and indexes, and data) are persistent across upgrades unless you manually delete them in `onupgradeneeded`. So to avoid that error, you should check `event.oldVersion` which will be 0 the first time the database is created and subsequently will be the previous version number. **Then you can either create your object store only when the database is first initialized or delete it before recreating it when upgrading.**

UPDATE: Relevant documentation on MDN [IDBDatabase.createObjectStore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/createObjectStore) which clarifies how using this call requires uniqueness.

> The createObjectStore() method of the IDBDatabase interface creates and returns a **new** object store or index.
>
> The method takes the name of the store as well as a parameter object that lets you define important optional properties. You can use the property to uniquely identify individual objects in the store. As the property is an identifier, **it should be unique to every object**, and every object should have that property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeremy, just one more question to be sure, a safe procedure will be on the lines of if oldversion === 0 then create objectStore, if olversion < version, do changes, if oldversion === version do nothing and if oldversion > version there is an exception that would be caught in an onerror?

Comment: you can get objectStoreNames and then use if(!objectStoreNames.contains('storename')) { ... }

Comment: PatomaS: That's what I do, except if oldVersion >= version then onupgradeneeded will never be called so you don't need to handle those situations.

Comment: Oldversion > version can never occure. Will result in an error when opening the db