# I'm unable to use YDN-DB ("Version change transaction was aborted in upgradeneeded event handler.")

Tags: ydn-db

I'm having a problem to start with YDN-DB. I mean. I set up a scheme, I initialized the database, but when instantiating throws an error that says "ConstraintError: DOM Exception IDBDatabase 0". In the event handler "fail" gives me "Version change transaction was aborted in upgradeneeded event handler.". Reading about the problem I found with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17772759). Can not find the way to assign an event to trigger "onupgradeneeded" and I think that would solve the problem

I leave my piece of code:

```
var shopgroups_schema = {
    name: 'shopgroups',
    keyPath: 'id_shop_group',
    autoIncrement: true,
    indexes: [
        {keyPath: 'id_shop_group'},
        {keyPath: 'name'},
        {keyPath: 'share_customer'},
        {keyPath: 'share_order'},
        {keyPath: 'share_stock'},
        {keyPath: 'active'},
        {keyPath: 'deleted'},
        {keyPath: 'date_add'},
        {keyPath: 'date_upd'},
        {keyPath: 'date_upd'}
    ]
};

var shops_schema = {
    name: 'shops',
    keyPath: 'id_shop',
    autoIncrement: true,
    indexes: [
        {keyPath: 'id_shop'},
        {keyPath: 'id_shop_group'},
        {keyPath: 'name'},
        {keyPath: 'id_category'},
        {keyPath: 'id_theme'},
        {keyPath: 'active'},
        {keyPath: 'deleted'},
        {keyPath: 'date_add'},
        {keyPath: 'date_upd'}
    ]
};

var schema = {
    stores: [shopgroups_schema, shops_schema]
};

var schemaName = 'chollingApp4';

var db = new ydn.db.Storage(schemaName, schema);

db.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
  var e = event.getError(); 
  // common errors are AbortError, ConstraintError and UnknownError (possibliy for Quota exceed error).
  // log error for debugging
  console.log('connection failed with ' + e.name);
});

db.addEventListener('fail', function (event) {
  var err = event.getError();
  console.log(event);
  console.log(err);
  console.log('connection failed with ' + err.name + ' by ' + err.message);
  db = null; // no operation can be placed to the database instance
});

db.addEventListener('ready', function (event) {
  var is_updated = event.getVersion() != event.getOldVersion();
  if (is_updated) {
    console.log('database connected with new schema');
  } else if (isNaN(event.getOldVersion()))  {
    console.log('new database created');
  } else {
    console.log('existing database connected');
  }
  // heavy database operations should start from this.
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConstraintError` in database opening suggest that schema could be a problem. I find you have index keyPath, `date_upd` repeated.